# Displaying text with transparent background

Tags: html, css

How can i display text with transparent background color
Over another background image or text?

I want to add text over an text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share what you've tried and where you are stuck on / what are the error messages you are getting?

Comment: @UsithaIndeewara Error messages in css :D

Comment: Just a mistake... Can't edit it now. Should be '....tried and what you are stuck on?' @Amini

Answer (score -2):

Something like this? The main trick here is to use `rgba` as `background-color`, where the last parameter is opacity (alpha chanel)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width:300px;
}

.container__image{
  width:100%;
}

.container__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:26px;
  color:red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" class="container__image"/>
  <span class="container__text">Some text</span>
</div>
```